# Error "Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, iis, compression, zip, icsharpcode

While executing the following code I observe an error in the line

```
public static void WriteZipFile(List<string> filesToZip, string path, int compression)
```

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Checksums;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

/* some code */

public static void WriteZipFile(List<string> filesToZip, string path, int compression)

/* some code */
Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
ZipOutputStream stream = new  ZipOutputStream(File.Create(path));
stream.SetLevel(compression);
```

Other info : Path = `C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\details\Local Code\\project\\projectwebsite\\PublishedSources\\`

Error:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\test\Documents\details\Local
>   Code\project\projectwebsite\PublishedSources\'.

Comment: Well, does this path exists on the computer running this code?

Comment: yes this path exists. When i tried to create a file using this path i get the same error. Is this something to do with iisexpress ?

Comment: Menioning IisExpress presumably this code is in a website? Check the file system permissions the account the website is running under has on the folder you're attempting to access; generally websites are run under accounts with very limited file system permissions.